# How to slide children at different speeds with CSS animation. Can this be done dynamically when # of children unknown?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to slide each of the children of the container element from right to left with the child elements completing the animation in order of top down.(item 1 completes animation then item 2, item3, etc.) How can I do this if the number of children is unknown?

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="child"> item 1</div>
        <div class="child"> item 2</div>
        <div class="child"> item 3</div>
        <div class="child"> item 4</div>
    </div>
```

I see a lot of guides on sliding from right to left on a single element. However, not seeing a way to slide individual items at various speeds, especially if the number of items is unknown.

Comment: Do you mean at different speeds, or just each one to wait for the previous one to finish before starting its animation?

Comment: At different speeds

Comment: Someone somewhere (probably in JS but could be built in HTML/CSS if a bit tedious) will need to know or find out the number of items. And how are the speeds determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the max number of items, you can set animation times for each of the possible elements.

Then you'll need to dynamically add a class to each element. Since the items are dynamically shown, I'm assuming you're using something like map.

```
items.map((items, itemCount=0)=> {
   //code to append class with itemCount++ at end
}
```

Then in your CSS you can do something like this

```
.item1 {
  animation: 100ms slide-left;
}

.item2 {
  animation: 200ms slide-left;
}
.item3 {
  animation: 300ms slide-left;
}

@keyframes slide-left {
  from {
    margin-left: 100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
```

Notice how we can use the same animation and just change the timing on each child element to make it slide faster or slower.

Comment: The animation of one element doesn't wait for the previous ones to finish. Was this removed as a requirement?

Answer (score 0):

first you will have to give every "child" its own class, you have them listed as the same class.
ex. child1, child 2,etc.
I have listed code below that I think is what you are asking.
There is commented out code that will explain what to do :)

Code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>JavaScript and the Canvas</title>
    
    <style>
 /* animate every child*/
 /*add an animation delay for each one so they will start one after the other 
 ex. if one starts at 3s then the next will be delayed by 3s so it starts after it*/
 /*if you want the animation to continue almost on a loop add: animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/

.container {
    background-color: aquamarine;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
.child1 {
    color: blue;
    animation-name: move1;
   animation-duration: 3s;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

}
@keyframes move1 {
 
 0% {
     transform: translate(0);
 }
 50% {
     transform: translate(100px);
 }
 100% {
     transform: translate(450px);
 }
 }

.child2 {
    color: blueviolet;
    animation-name: move2;
   animation-duration: 3s;
   animation-delay: 3s;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes move2 {
 
 0% {
     transform: translate(0);
 }
 50% {
     transform: translate(100px);
 }
 100% {
     transform: translate(450px);
 }
 }
.child3 {
    color: brown;
    animation-name: move3;
   animation-duration: 3s;
   animation-delay: 6s;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes move3 {
 
 0% {
     transform: translate(0);
 }
 50% {
     transform: translate(100px);
 }
 100% {
     transform: translate(450px);
 }
 }

    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
 <!--give each child in the container a diffrent class, not the same class-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="child1"> item 1</div>
        <div class="child2"> item 2</div>
        <div class="child3"> item 3</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question asks if we can do the animation when the number of children is dynamic. Your solution works when the number of children is known, but a dynamic one will be more helpful!